# How can I persist local storage data from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools, vue-component

I’ve nearly finished with my first Vue.js app and the last thing I need to do is persist my local storage data so that I can access it on another page. I’ll give you an example.

At the moment, these are the local storage methods I have (along with some less relevant data properties):

```
data() {
    return {
      testData: [],
      testDataIndex: 0,
      selectedIndex: null,
      submittedIndex: null,
      healthScore: 0,
    }
  }, 
computed: {
    setHealthScore() {
      localStorage.setItem('SavedHealthScore', this.healthScore)
    },
    getHealthScore() {
      localStorage.getItem('SavedHealthScore')
    },
  },
```

This is a health quiz app. So, after the user answers the final question, I want he/she to be taken to the final page (this changes the route) so that a ‘health score’ can be returned. Throughout the quiz, the health score increments by a certain value depending on which answer the user gives. The computed methods above successfully track the health score and keep it in local storage. That is, until the user finishes the quiz and reaches the final page. Then, the health score in local storage goes back to 0 because that’s what the original health score reverts back to.

I want the health score in local storage to save the last known value of the original health score before it goes back to 0. This way, I can return the health score in local storage to display to the user. Right now, the final page simply renders 0/21 regardless of the answers given, obviously, this isn’t what I want.

How can I prevent my local storage health score from returning back to 0?

P.S. I’m aware Vuex could potentially solve this issue but understanding local storage is more important to me right now than learning Vuex.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is just because data sample is lacking context, but given this code in `this.healthScore`,  `this` refers to the `computed` object, where `healthScore` is `undefined`.

Comment: localStorage is persisted between pages of a domain by default, that's how it works; have you inspected the contents of localStorage in the browser's dev tools to make sure it contains what you think it does?

Comment: @pawel The computed functions are tracking the health score successfully as the local storage health score updates as the original health score does. But when I change page, the local storage health score mimics the original health score and goes back to 0. I sense that there is an issue with my logic somewhere.

Comment: @ChrisG The computed properties behave as you would expect when I change page. I know this because I've inspected local storage in dev tools and the Vue Chrome extension. Everything probably works fine. But from a logical and programmatical standpoint, I don't know how to get my health score in my local storage to not return back to 0 after I've changed page. I think there may be some faulty logic in my JS but of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your app currently actively overwrites the score in localStorage with `0`, and you're asking how to prevent that?

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves A long shot, but are you testing this with separate documents via `file:///` protocol, or on a server (localhost or public)? It probably wouldn't persist between different files, but would between pages on the same domain.

Comment: @ChrisG Exactly.

Comment: @pawel Two different pages on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are some choices for handling persistent storage, however, your problem in your code is your setting storage based on a computed property. The moment the component is unmounted, the computed property will revert to a default, in your case 0. You can see this in action if you change your default score from 0 to 1, and refresh your app, you will notice localstorage reverts to a 1 after a test.

**EDIT:** Adding commented answer for additional information.

You can move it to a button click maybe on save or submit, or even add some logic to the computed if you truly want to keep it computed.

`if(this.healthScore != 0) {
    localStorag.setItem(this.healthScore)
}`

Your Retrieval needs to get from localStorage and assign back to the local variable

```
getHealthScore() {
  this.healthScore = localStorage.getItem('SavedHealthScore')
},
```

That way it will only set local storage if the test score is not 0.

**You need to call the set storage from a different event, and not from the computed property. Or you need to add logic to prevent the computed from always saving to local storage**

(You are already aware but I will tell you anyway in case its helpful)

Persistent storage choices:

**1)** you use the browser `localStorage` and store information there which will persist until the user clears out their browser, however, in your case you may want to consider `sessionStorage` since it will clear when they leave your app. There ais not a need to install any NPM packages for these as they are already available. code snippet below in case you want to create one method, if you want to use Session instead just change `localStorage`  to `sessionStorage` and viola.

```
**
 * Adds an item to Storage
 * @param key The Key value
 * @param value The String Value to be Stored
 */
export function AddToStorage(key: string, value: string): any {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}
```

**2)** Another slightly more complex choice but one you will see used in mid to large level project is `Vuex` which is Vue's ways of handling state when transitioning through the app. The set-up for it is a little complex and is overkill for your project that is already almost done, but if you want to dip your toes into it, this would be a good opportunity.

Comment: Which event would you recommend if not the computed property? mounted()? I think you're right about sessions. They would be a more appropriate choice for my app. No reason to keep the data after the user closes the app. However, I did replace localStorage with sessionStorage as you suggested and the health score now isn't being tracked. I'm aware Vuex could solve my issue but I fear learning that may take more time than solving this issue with local storage.

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves You can move it to a button click maybe on save or submit, or even add some logic to the computed if you truly want to keep it computed. maybe if(scoe != 0) {localStorag.setItem()} That way it will only set local storage if the test score is not 0.

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves from the code you have provided can't give you a specific event since I do not see any available. But an @click="saveToStorage" would work when they submit their score or request their score ect.

Comment: Adding the logic to the computed function worked for me. That was the exact kind of answer I was looking for! Now all I need to do is render savedHealthScore from local storage. I've tried using {{ getHealthScore }} but nothing returns.

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves If you are saving to sessionStorage as you stated earlier you need to also get from session Storage. Same as local Storage just change to sessionStorage

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves I updated my answer to include my comments as well, in case someone else finds it useful. If you found the complete answer useful please mark it as the answer for future reference.

Comment: I'm not using session storage anymore as that wasn't working for me. I'm trying {{ getHealthScore }} but my page will say ' /21'. I'm not sure how to fetch and render 'SavedHealthScore' from local storage.

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves Your code is missing its assingment back to the healthScore.  I updated my answer as well as provide it here   getHealthScore() {
      this.healthScore =  localStorage.getItem('SavedHealthScore')
    },

Comment: I've fixed that. Thanks. The function does it's job now, except for some strange reason, only when I'm viewing the health score under 'App' in the Vue dev tools. I'm very confused by this.

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves Maybe post up a new question on SO? im not sure i understand and I don;t want to dilute the original post with a different follow up question.

Comment: Yeah, I'll put a new post up.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use computed methods to set values in local storage inside of each components. The better way to set value in local storage when value is undefined or changed. code snippet is as below:

```
let healthScore = localStorage.getItem("healthScore");
if(healthScore == undefined) {
  localStorage.setItem("healthScore");
}
```

You should first check is there any value assigned in local storage. if not then assign a default value, in your case set value to 0.